# Cuando extraigo el valor de un objeto dentro del init me aparece undefined

Tags: reactjs

Necesito obtener el valor identificación de un objeto que obtengo de un Context para enviarlo a mi backend para que me retorne lo que pido.

```
const Recetas = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ picture: "" });
  const { globalState } = useContext(MainContext);

  const [RecetasList, setRecetasList] = useState([]);

  const init = async () => {
    setUser(globalState.auth);
    console.log(user.identification);
    const { data } = await ApiRequest().get("/recetas", user.identification);
    setRecetasList(data);
  };
};
```

Pero al ejecutar `console.log(user.identification)` me imprime undefined.
Pero si lo saco del init si me imprime la identificador del usuario.
El punto es que lo necesito dentro del init para poder enviar al backend el valor

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola Walter, en que punto llamas `init()`? `useState`  es asíncrono por ende puede que al utilizar ese valor aun no exista. Es lo que se me puede estar ocurriendo

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

el problema que tienes es que el setState es asíncrono por lo que necesitas hacer uso del hook useEffect para que ejecute tu lógica al detectar un cambio en tu variable state.

Basicamente useEffect se puede utilizar de 3 maneras diferentes, que son:

1. Cada vez que renderizamos el componente, esto se logra quitando el array después de su declaración.
2. Solo la primera vez que renderiza el componente; esto se logra enviando un arreglo vacío sin props o state.
3. Cuando se renderiza el componente y/o cuando el la propiedad state que pasas dentro del arreglo sufre un cambio

En tu caso en particular necesitas la 3ra opción en la que pasas dentro del arreglo la receta de listas, solo debes tener cuidado de hacer las validaciones correspondientes para que no arroje una excepción al renderizar el component por primera vez.

Te quedaría algo así:

```
const Recetas = () => {
const [user, setUser] = useState({ picture: "" });
const { globalState } = useContext(MainContext);

const [RecetasList, setRecetasList] = useState([]);

const init = async () => {
  setUser(globalState.auth);
};

useEffect(() => {
    //validación inicial dado que en el primer render el objeto no tendrá esa propiedad
    if(user?.identification != null){
        const { data } = await ApiRequest().get("/recetas", user.identification);
        setRecetasList(data);      
    }
  }, 
  //enviamos el state que queremos dispare esta función al momento de sufrir un cambio
  [user]);
  };
```

También te sugeriría que en lugar de disparar esa función al hacer el cambio en el state lo ejecutes inmediatamente que lo seteas pero utilizando:

```
const Recetas = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ picture: "" });
  const { globalState } = useContext(MainContext);

  const [RecetasList, setRecetasList] = useState([]);

  const init = async () => {
    setUser(globalState.auth);
    const { data } = await ApiRequest().get("/recetas", globalState.auth.identification);
    setRecetasList(data);
  };
};
```

A menos que haya un motivo especifico por el cual necesites que user tenga su valor antes de hacer el llamado.